# Java Selenium wait for element with timeout

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm developing a test unit with Selenium FirefoxDriver in Java. I'd like some help handling the page load. My problem is waiting for elements while still have a timeout. I already tried applying `pageLoadTimeout`,`implicitlyWait` with no success, some methods continue to wait for full page load. A preview of my code:

```
    (...)
    FirefoxDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    try {
       driver.get("http://mysite");
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
       //after 1 milisecond get method timeouts
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {//5 seconds wait
            if (driver.findElements(By.id("wait_id")).size() == 0) { //findElements cause java to wait for full load
                debug("not found");//never happens because 'if' condition waits for full load
                driver.wait(1000);
            } else {
                debug("found");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you do run your Firefox [with unstable loading strategy](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#-Beta-_load_fast_preference), right? In that case, I guess it won't work since the functionality is beta, incomplete and Firefoxy-only. =/ But we'll see, maybe somebody has some thouth on this.

Comment: No, I wasn't using that profile pref... I will try it later and post results.

Comment: yet that seems to meet my goal. Post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pageLoadTimeout()` method only works properly with Firefox run with ["unstable load strategy"](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#-Beta-_load_fast_preference). Therefore, run your `FirefoxDriver` like this:

```
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
```

Note that it only works under Firefox, really is unstable, and could make some of your other tests fail. Use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static WebElement waitForElement(WebDriver driver, By by) {

    WebElement element = null;
    int counter = 0;
    while (element == null) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            element = driver.findElement(by);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (counter > 119) {
            System.out.println("System has timed out");
        }
                    counter++;
    }
    return element;
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.get is a blocking call, and waits for the page to load.
Since you set the timeout to 1 millisecond a Timeout exception is thrown.
You can see it if you put a `e.printStackTrace();` in your `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException` cacht block.

Set the timeout to -1.

Comment: yes `wait` gives error but changing that doesn't fix the real issue.

Comment: Ok in addition to `Thread.sleep(1000);`
setting timeout works for me.
See my edited Answer.